# What badges are relevant for moderator election?

Tags: support, badges, moderator-election

For each candidate in the [election pages](https://stackoverflow.com/election/11) there's a small box with the candidate's score.

[image: example of candidate's score box]

It show the candidate's reputation and a given set of badges. Civic Duty, Strunk & White, Deputy and Convention are explicitly named in the election page. But that's not the case for "moderation badges", "editing badges" or "participation badges".

The [badges page](https://stackoverflow.com/help/badges) has seven sections. Two of them are "moderation badges" and "participation badges", but there's no way to tell which of the listed badges are taken in consideration during the election. "Participation badges", for instance, lists 17 badges, but only 6 are considered for election purposes. How to tell them apart?

Comment: If you mouse over the labels like "moderation badges" it tells you

Comment: @Ivar Couldn't have found that before I listed them all in an answer (now deleted)? :P